# Null Pointer Exception while executeUpdate for a query using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

I am getting a Null Pointer Exception while executing the insert query. Everything seems to be fine but the problem still exists.

Code used for Database Connection.

```
public class DBConnect 
{
    static Connection c ;
    static Statement st ;
    {
        try 
        {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","ashuthesmartest","ashutosha");
            st=c.createStatement();
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Database error");
        }
    }   
}
```

Action Performed on Button Click

```
private void b3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    try 
    {
        char[] arr = pa1.getPassword() ;
        String s2 = Arrays.toString(arr) ;
        String s1 = t3.getText() ;
        DBConnect.st.executeUpdate("insert into LOGIN values('"+s1+"','"+s2+"')");   **//EXCEPTION IN THIS LINE**
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initialization block in which you create the connection and the statement is not a static initialization block.

Therefore, it will only be executed when you create an instance of the class `DBConnect`.

Since you seem to be using `DBConnect` only statically, that never happens. Your initialization block should be made static. A static initialization block has the keyword `static` preceding the left brace:

```
static {
    // try etc.
}
```

Comment: Oh Dear ! That was a very silly mistake, I regret committing. Thanks for your help RealSkeptic.